# Use SNMP set with RowStatus type

Tags: snmp

I'm confused about how the RowStatus type works and what value I need to pass to be able to set the values in other columns in the row. From researching it seems like I'm either doing the wrong order of operations or not passing the right values along with the RowStatus value.

This device uses a webGUI and I'm using SNMP to script some mass config changes. In the GUI you check a box to enable the row before cells in the row become active allowing you to enter info.

Here's what the row status shows before it gets enabled:

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c testcomm -m +MY-MIB 172.28.183.150 MY-MIB::mibRowStatus.101.1 MY-MIB::mibRowStatus.101.1 = INTEGER: notInService(2)
```

Whether I try with just the createAndWait or createAndGo value to try just enabling the row I get a wrong type. Here's how I tried sending values for each row along with the createAndWait value. Same happened when trying createAndGo. Am I doing multiple OID/values correctly?

```
snmpset -v 2c -c testcomm -m +MY-MIB 172.28.183.150 MY-MIB::mibRowStatus.101.1 = createAndWait iso.3.6.1.4.1.xx.101.1 = 1 iso.3.6.1.4.1.xx.101.1 = "test" iso.3.6.1.4.1.xx.101.1 = 15 iso.3.6.1.4.1.xx.101.1 = md6 iso.3.6.1.4.1.xx.101.1 = 6 iso.3.6.1.4.1.xx.101.1 = 4 iso.3.6.1.4.1.xx.101.1 = 7
Error in packet.
Reason: wrongType (The set datatype does not match the data type the agent expects)
Failed object: MY-MIB::mibRowStatus.101.1
```

It works if I destroy the row.

```
snmpset -v 2c -c testcomm -m +MY-MIB 172.28.183.150 MY-MIB::mibRowStatus.101.1 = destroy
MY-MIB::mibRowStatus.101.1 = INTEGER: destroy(6)
```

I'm able to enable the row through the GUI and SNMP set the rest of the values but that defeats the purpose. It returns active(1) if I do everything through GUI and do a snmpwalk.

Here is what the vendor MIB says:

```
mibRowStatus OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      RowStatus
    MAX-ACCESS  read-create
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
       "The status of the row.

        The writable columns in a row can not be changed if the row
        is active. All columns must have a valid value before a row
        can be activated. 
        
       "
   ::= { mibEntry 22 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out. The values all need to be set before sending the RowStatus.

For example I sent just the values:

```
snmpset -v 2c -c testcomm -m +MY-MIB 172.28.183.150 iso.3.6.1.4.1.xx.101.1 = 1 iso.3.6.1.4.1.xx.101.1 = "test" iso.3.6.1.4.1.xx.101.1 = 15 iso.3.6.1.4.1.xx.101.1 = md6 iso.3.6.1.4.1.xx.101.1 = 6 iso.3.6.1.4.1.xx.101.1 = 4 iso.3.6.1.4.1.xx.101.1 = 7
```

It sets them:

```
MY-MIB::mibCciEnabled.101.1 = INTEGER: true(1)
MY-MIB::mibMepMaName.101.1 = STRING: test
MY-MIB::mibMepId.101.1 = INTEGER: 15
MY-MIB::mibMepMdName.101.1 = STRING: md6
MY-MIB::mibMepLevel.101.1 = INTEGER: 6
MY-MIB::mibMepCcmInterval.101.1 = INTEGER: interval1s(4)
MY-MIB::mibMepCcmLtmPriority.101.1 = Gauge32: 7
```

Then the RowStatus has to be set:

```
snmpset -v 2c -c testcomm -m +OVERTURE-SOAM-MIB 172.28.183.150 MY-MIB::mibRowStatus.101.1 = createAndGo
MY-MIB::mibRowStatus.101.1 = INTEGER: createAndGo(4)
```